# Focus onload not working properly

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working with a windows application.(.net/c#)
on load I want to make first/default control as selected and start dataEntry without using mouse.

[image: Figure1]

After I add `this.ActiveControl = myTextbox;` OR `myTextbox .Select();`It would work fine looking on UI

[image: figure2]

but the same is not active or typable without using mouse initially. I tried the same for Company combobox also and not working expected manner.

I Tried with Focus() as well.

Code:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) 
{ 
    base.OnLoad(e);
    _context = new CompanyContext();
    companyList = _context.Companies.ToList();
    var companylist = new BindingList<BPS.Data.Entities.Company>(companyList);
    metroComp.DataSource = companylist;
    metroComp.DisplayMember = "CompanyName";
    metroComp.ValueMember = "CompanyName";
    this.ActiveControl = myTextBox;
    //myTextBox.Select();// Tried this line also and working same effect
}
```

I tried that code in Form_Load also

Comment: Maybe show us some of your code... we can see what you are doing wrong then

Comment: have you initialized the component?

Comment: Be careful with `OnLoad`, you may have an [exception in there that's not being caught](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933958/vs2010-does-not-show-unhandled-exception-message-in-a-winforms-application-on-a).

Comment: long code in comment is too difficult to read. moved code to question.

Comment: agree with @bokibeg. try `this.Activate()` also your form may not be the active parent control.

Comment: Qn Edited .@kevintjuh93;@bansi;@rajesmpanachal

Comment: Hurreh... It's been working.. Thanks a lot !!@bansi

Comment: I think you need to InitializeComponent(); in onLoad event.

Comment: @b_in_u Just use the `Shown` event instead and put `myTextBox.Focus()` inside it. That's the classic way of doing it. You can override `OnShown` if you want for the same effect.

Comment: @bansi. Please add this as answer.

Comment: would calling base.OnLoad(e) at the end make any difference (or work at all)?

Comment: can you please try by adding this two lines in your code,  InitializeComponent();
            myTextBox.Focus();

Comment: @rajeshmpanchal . this is also working and nice solution too Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also add below line of code,

`this.Activate();`

To your form. It may not be the active parent control. when the form is shown.

I would suggest to activate the form at the end of the Load event. so the form becomes the active form in the application.

Answer (score 1):

So I think this is working code for your case,

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);
            _context = new CompanyContext();
            companyList = _context.Companies.ToList();
            var companylist = new BindingList<BPS.Data.Entities.Company>(companyList);
            metroComp.DataSource = companylist;
            metroComp.DisplayMember = "CompanyName";
            metroComp.ValueMember = "CompanyName";
            InitializeComponent();
            myTextBox.Focus();
        }
```

Comment: not need --> this.ActiveControl = myTextBox; thankyou